# Why does iptables forward from one network but not another?

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have LAN (10.20.1.0/24) and WLAN (172.16.20.0/24) traffic arriving on `ens32` and destined for 10.21.0.1 via OpenVPN `tun0` on a Debian 9 system. `iptables` is forwarding from LAN, but not from WLAN.

Using a TRACE rule in `iptables`, I get the following via the LAN:

```
May 14 15:03:07 vpnsrv kernel: [2357925.893248] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=... SRC=10.20.1.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57269 DPT=22 SEQ=3284245311 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E55489B0000000004020000) 
May 14 15:03:07 vpnsrv kernel: [2357925.893288] TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=... SRC=10.20.1.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57269 DPT=22 SEQ=3284245311 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E55489B0000000004020000) 
May 14 15:03:07 vpnsrv kernel: [2357925.893317] TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=ens32 OUT=tun0 MAC=... SRC=10.20.1.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57269 DPT=22 SEQ=3284245311 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E55489B0000000004020000) 
May 14 15:03:07 vpnsrv kernel: [2357925.893347] TRACE: filter:ufw-before-logging-forward:return:1 IN=ens32 OUT=tun0 MAC=... SRC=10.20.1.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57269 DPT=22 SEQ=3284245311 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E55489B0000000004020000) 
May 14 15:03:07 vpnsrv kernel: [2357925.893365] TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:2 IN=ens32 OUT=tun0 MAC=... SRC=10.20.1.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57269 DPT=22 SEQ=3284245311 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E55489B0000000004020000) 
May 14 15:03:07 vpnsrv kernel: [2357925.893388] TRACE: filter:ufw-before-forward:rule:8 IN=ens32 OUT=tun0 MAC=... SRC=10.20.1.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57269 DPT=22 SEQ=3284245311 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E55489B0000000004020000) 
May 14 15:03:07 vpnsrv kernel: [2357925.893404] TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:policy:3 IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=10.20.1.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57269 DPT=22 SEQ=3284245311 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E55489B0000000004020000)
```

but only the first part via the WLAN:

```
May 14 15:08:44 vpnsrv kernel: [2358263.328390] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=... SRC=172.16.20.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57342 DPT=22 SEQ=3290971808 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E5A69C30000000004020000)
May 14 15:08:44 vpnsrv kernel: [2358263.328430] TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=... SRC=172.16.20.12 DST=10.21.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57342 DPT=22 SEQ=3290971808 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303050101080A0E5A69C30000000004020000)
```

Relevant filter rules are:

```
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A ufw-before-forward -i ens32 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Why doesn't traffic from WLAN get forwarded?

Comment: Do you use policy routing? If so - showing rules and routing tables may be relevant here. Additionally please show your routing table entry for the 172.16.20.0/24 network as you may be hitting rp_filter if this is not set correctly.

Comment: Aha! The OpenVPN server didn't have a route back to 172.16.20.0/24 because the default gateway is on the DMZ (192.168.20.0/24), not the LAN.  Adding that got my packets routing to `tun0`, and then `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.20.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE` made sure the remote server could reply. Write this up as an answer and I'll give you the points. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you use policy routing? If so - showing rules and routing tables may be relevant here. Additionally please show your routing table entry for the 172.16.20.0/24 network as you may be hitting rp_filter if this is not set correctly